# Finding Id, Text of Input types through C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have saved input (text,checkbox,dropdownlist) in one html page, and am loading that in asp:panel, after loading users can enter values in that. Now by Clicking Asp:button i have to find that input types and save to database, how can it achieved.

the input code will be in this format .

```
<label style="left: 46px; top: 73px; position: relative;" id="Llb1" onmouseup="MLup(this.id)" class="ui-draggable" onmousedown="MLdown(this.id)"> Enter the value </label>
<input style="left: 170px; top: 113px; position: relative;" id="T1" onmouseup="mUp(this.id)" class="ui-draggable"  onmousedown="mDown(this.id)" value="" type="text">
```

This input types i have to find those ids, and text... how can it possible..

Comment: Why don't you replace your html page with asp.net page and give attribute runat="server" to your input types?

Comment: Actually that input types was dynamically created through Jquery code.

Comment: In that case you might need to register your dynamically created controls to asp.net form .

Comment: Request.Form will do the trick. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337418/access-html-controls-from-code-behind-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i got a solution for finding the id of text,select, labels through html Button click

```
 <input type="button" id="save" value="submit" onclick="submitpage()" />
```

then on submitpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function submitpage() {
              var completeids = new Array();
              var completevalues = new Array();
              var completetype = new Array();
              var completeselected = new Array();
              var labelvalues = new Array();
             // var name = "abc";
              var name = document.getElementById('<%=username.ClientID %>').innerHTML
              $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
                  completeids.push($(this).attr('id'));
                  completetype.push('TEXTBOX');
                  completevalues.push($(this).attr('value'));
                  completeselected.push('no');

              });
              $('label').each(function () {
                  completeids.push($(this).attr('id'));
                  completevalues.push($('label[id= ' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').html());
                  labelvalues.push($('label[id= ' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').html());
                  completetype.push('LABEL');
                  completeselected.push('no');

              });
              $('select').each(function () {
                  completeids.push($(this).attr('id'));
                  completevalues.push($(this).val());
                  completetype.push('DROPDOWN');
                  completeselected.push('no');

              });
              $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                  completeids.push($(this).attr('id'));
                  completevalues.push($('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').html());
                  completetype.push('CHECKBOX');
                  completeselected.push($(this).attr('checked'));

              });
              $('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
                  completeids.push($(this).attr('id'));
                  completevalues.push($('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').html());
                  completetype.push('RADIOBUTTON');
                  completeselected.push($(this).attr('checked'));

              });
              $('input[type="file"]').each(function () {
                  completeids.push($(this).attr('id'));
                  //completevalues.push('not yet done');
                  completevalues.push($(this).attr('value'));

                  completetype.push('FILE');
                  completeselected.push('no');

              });

              var loc = window.location.href;
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: loc + "/GetSaved",
                  data: "{getcompleteids :'" + completeids + "',getcompletevalues :'" + completevalues + "',getcompletetypes :'" + completetype + "',getcompleteselected :'" + completeselected + "',getlabelvalue :'" + labelvalues + "',formname:'"+name+"'}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

              })
            .success(function (response) {
                alert(response.d);

            })
            .error(function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            });

          }

    </script>
```

at c# code i have used like this...

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string GetSaved(string getcompleteids, string getcompletevalues, string getcompletetypes, string getcompleteselected, string getlabelvalue, string formname)
    {

        string[] completeids = getcompleteids.Split(',');
        string[] completevalues = getcompletevalues.Split(',');
        string[] completetypes = getcompletetypes.Split(',');
        string[] completeselected = getcompleteselected.Split(',');
        string[] labelvalues = getlabelvalue.Split(',');
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dynamic"].ConnectionString);
        string FORMNAME = labelvalues[0];
        for (int i = 0; i <= completeids.Length-1; i++)
        {
            con.Open();
                                                                                        //FORM_NAME,     USER_NAME         ,CONTRO_TYPE,             CONTROL_ID,        CONTROL_VALUE,                CONTROL_SELECTED
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CONTROLS_INFORMATION VALUES('" + FORMNAME + "',' "+formname+" ','" + completetypes[i] + "','" + completeids[i] + "','" + completevalues[i] + "','" + completeselected[i] + "')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }



        return "successfully";

    }
```

It was done..
Hope it will be useful to some one like me..hmm...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't get label's value on server. For getting dynamic textbox value you need to assign `name` attribute on it and get value on postback from `Request.Form` collection by that name.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options to achieve it.

- Create some hidden fields also along with the fields you are creating and put the field type value and other required meta data in the hidden fields. When you post the form, these hidden fields will serve you the metadata about the form which you can use to properly insert it in database.

or

- When you dynamically create the control, inform the server about it using ajax request so that server has prior knowledge of these fields. You can store this information in session and when the form post back, you can use it to obtain the data from request object.

In either case, you have to use the raw request object to get the values of the fields as asp.net will not parse those fields which were not present on the page as they will not be the part of view state.

It is a good idea to post the entire form using ajax rather then posting it in normal way. This way, you could be sure that only the dynamic data is posted.